# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/messages/Messages$Envelope

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

[image: Error Snapshot]

I am using Selenium and Cucumber with Java. While executing "Feature" file of Cucumber, I am facing this issue.

Versions: Java 15.0.1 2020-10-20

**Error Log:**

```
Dec 23, 2020 11:03:54 AM cucumber.api.cli.Main run
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/messages/Messages$Envelope
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.NoPublishFormatter.setEventPublisher(NoPublishFormatter.java:34)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.Plugins.setEventBusOnEventListenerPlugins(Plugins.java:71)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$Builder.build(Runtime.java:180)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:90)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:30)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.messages.Messages$Envelope
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: A code snippet would be helpful

Comment: It looks like you don't have all necessary dependencies on the classpath. Please show your build definition (pom.xml or build.gradle), or at least the dependencies you declared.